# How could i do a list without duplicate data?

Tags: java, list, set

I want to do a SET or LIST without duplicates, but also want access your index. For exemple: setvariable.get(0).getName(). To access the object.

In java documentation is not recommended that use conditions to eliminate the duplicates in a list.
Then, how could i do?

I'm trying create an association between two objects, course and student. But i don't want that both to have duplicated data.

Thank you very much in advance!

Note:
I was trying to do a project but i was having problems of knowledge in association of OOP, and i come back for practice. At this time i'm doing exercise to practice OOP that i was having difficultly. Then i'm practicing OOP thinking ahead of the exercise implementing conditions that in fact dificult a real program, as duplicates. And how the teacher resolve all exercise with your index i was getting confused in keeping your index, but in fact seeing the explanations is not something necessary.

Solution: Use the SET because the index is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Don't add something to the list if it is already in the list.

Comment: Have you tried using Map?

Comment: Does it have to bw implemented as `List` or `Set`?

Comment: *"I want to do a `SET` or `LIST` without duplicates"* - are you aware that [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) is a collection of unique elements, its implementations can't contain duplicates. I would advise you to get familiar with the basic information about [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html) and clarify the problem since it's unclear what do you need to achieve (but first take a time to read the linked tutorial, it'll give a better understanding of your problem).

Comment: Explain why you care about the order. By what logic are the elements to be sorted? Voting to close for lack of detail.

Comment: I was trying to do a project but i was having problems of knowledge in association of OOP, and i come back for practice.
At this time i'm doing exercise to practice OOP that i was having difficultly. Then i'm practicing OOP thinking ahead of the exercise implementing conditions that in fact dificult a real program, as duplicates.
And how the teacher resolve all exercise with your index i was getting confused in keeping your index, but in fact seeing the explanations is not something necessary.

Thanks very much for the help and sorry if my question is so beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to explain that Java doesn't have an "indexable" set class ... but then I looked at what you are actually trying to implement.

I going to assume that the association you are trying to implement is many-to-many.  In the real world, a student may take many courses, and a course may be taken by many students.  I assume your are trying to model that in your program.

The natural way to represent a (queryable) many-to-many association between two Java classes is using a pair of `Map` objects; e.g.

```
   Map<Student, Set<Course>> enrolledCourses;
   Map<Course, Set<Student>> enrolledStudents;
```

Depending on the kind of queries you need to perform, the maps could be `HashMap` or `TreeMap`.  Each time you add or remove a relation between a `Student` and a `Course` you will need to update both `Map` objects.

Assuming that you maintain the maps correctly, there won't be any duplicate copies of either `Student` or `Course` objects.

On the other hand, if the association doesn't need to be queryable, you can get away with `Set` valued fields; e.g.

```
  // In the Course class
  Set<Student> enrolledStudents;
  
  // In the Student class
  Set<Course> enrolledCourses;
```

You could also use a `List` class and use `contains` to remove duplicates manually.  That will lead to `O(N)` insertion and deletion operations, but that *may* be acceptable under normal real world assumptions.  (Course enrollment numbers will typically be capped, and a student will only be allowed to enroll in a limited number of courses.)

---

Note that your idea of using list positions as some kind of identifier is not practical.  When you remove an element in the middle of a list, all following elements in the list change positions.  Positions are not stable in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want that there are duplicates in the combinations or each list should not contain any duplicates?

For the second option you can check your list by using **.contains** before adding any additional element:

```
        List<String> testList = null;
        String element = null;
        
        if (testList.contains(element)) {
            testList.add(element);
        }
```